# Directory browsing in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, lighttpd

I'm want to write a PHP code where I want to browse through multiple directories in a web browser. My directory structure is something like this:

```
MAIN DIR 
 -> SUB DIR1 
   -> sub dir1
      -> *downloadable PDF files*
   -> sub dir2
      -> *downloadable PDF files*
   -> sub dir3
      -> *downloadable PDF files*

 -> SUB DIR2 
   -> sub dir1
      -> *downloadable PDF files*
   -> sub dir2
      -> *downloadable PDF files*
   -> sub dir3
      -> *downloadable PDF files*

 -> SUB DIR3 
   -> sub dir1
      -> *downloadable PDF files*
   -> sub dir2
      -> *downloadable PDF files*
   -> sub dir3
      -> *downloadable PDF files*
```

So far I'm only able to list the directories. Can anyone help me in how should I move ahead? 
I'm using `lighttpd` server.

Comment: I have created a similar code here https://github.com/gopalindians/serve-directory/       
   you need to loop through the all the content in the directory and if it is a file let the user download or see it, if it is a directory let him in and repeat.

Comment: @GopalSharma Thanks for the code.. I'll go through it

Comment: @GopalSharma In your code, when I click on any folder, it gets downloaded as html file rather than showing it's content.

Comment: It is just for your idea on how to proceed, I have filtered the directory listing in the code  check line number 51 `https://github.com/gopalindians/serve-directory/blob/master/index.php#L51`

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code you will get all list in arrays
function dirToArray($dir) { 

   $result = array(); 

   $cdir = scandir($dir); 
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
   { 
      if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
      { 
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
         { 
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $result[] = $value; 
         } 
      } 
   } 

   return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An entirely different option would be to use mod_webdav and use WebDAV to browse the files.